How can i use grep to pull all maiboxes with 10 digits?
this is one of the lines in my file, I'd like to grep for all 10 digit numbers in the file.
":0,"msgtran":"000168251115"}],"source":{"extension":"01","mailbox":"0123456789","application":


I don't think grep is what you want. Grep will return a line w/the pattern in it. Not just the number. Regardless, try grep [0123456789]... and repeat the square brackets sequence 10 times (grep [0123..9][012..][0..]...[0..]). Not enough room here to type it all out. If that's the answer you were looking for, "@" me and I'll post it as an answer. But like I said, I am thinking that is not what you are looking for.

@st2000 grep has a -o option that allows it to output only the matching portion of the line - for example grep -oP '(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)'. If the file is in JSON format there are likely more appropriate tools than grep though.

looks like a json.... why not use python? takes about 10 lines of code to print the value of [source][mailbox] If this is one time you can also do this online :)

If what you want is to "grep for all 10 digit numbers in the file", then all you need is:
grep -oP '\d{10}'

The -o tells grep to only print the matching portion of the line, and the -P enables PCRE (a specific flavor of regular expressions) which gives us the \d shorthand for "digits". We then tell it to only look for exactly 10 digits with {10}.
Now, this isn't actually what you want, most likely, since that will find all occurrences of 10 digits, including the first 10 numbers in a 12-digit number, for example. So you need to limit this to stretches of 10 digits surrounded by non-digit numbers. For this, you can use regex lookarounds:
$ grep -oP '(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)' file
0123456789

Or, since it looks like your numbers are quoted, just look for the quotes:
$ grep -oP '"\d{10}"' file
"0123456789"

You can later remove them with tr:
$ grep -oP '"\d{10}"' file | tr -d '"'
0123456789

Or use lookarounds again:
$ grep -oP '(?<=")\d{10}(?=")' file
0123456789

Perhaps what you really want is the quoted number that comes after the string "mailbox":. If so, you can do:
$ grep -oP '"mailbox":"\K\d{10}"' file | tr -d '"'
0123456789

The \K means "forget anything matched until here" so we don't include anything before the \K in the output of grep -oP, and then we just look for exactly 10 digits followed by a " and finally remove the " again.
IMPORTANT: this looks like a JSON file, in which case you really don't want to use grep and should instead use a proper JSON parser like jq. I can't help with that since you haven't given us valid JSON, but if the file is valid JSON, please try to use a dedicated tool.

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:
$ awk -v RS='"[0-9]{10}"' 'RT{print substr(RT,2,10)}' file
0123456789

or using any POSIX awk:
$ awk -F'"' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[0-9]{10}$/) print $i}' file
0123456789

